# Stop Fullscreen Window from going to back when other App clicked in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

alright so I am trying to make an Application using JavaFx, that displays the currently playing song in the background on my second screen in fullscreen, while I use my other screen to do work. Similar to [this](http://codepen.io/jmperez/pen/MmwObE).
Anyhow, when I made it go in fullscreen it was all fine, but once I tabbed out was put to back, just like if the #toBack() function would've been fired, behind all other applications that are open on that screen. I tried to avoid that by adding a ChangeListener to the focusProperty:

```
stage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(oldValue) Platform.runLater(() -> {
            stage.toFront();
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        });
    });
```

Then it was all good, it would stay in the front while I used my other screen, but then when I tried to display another app on the screen, where my fullscreen display was running on, my application would stay infront, anyhow, this is not because of the ChangeListener added to the focusProperty, it just acts like it would be set to always on top.

**My Issue:** How do I get the app to stay in fullscreen, but not go to the back of the screen when it loses focus, but also not having it AlwaysOnTop.

Thank you for any help already <3

**Edit:**
Code to reproduce my issue:

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

       primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
       

       primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
           if(oldValue) {
               System.out.println("Fired");
               Platform.runLater(() ->  primaryStage.toFront());
               primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
           }
       });

       primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
           if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.F11) {
               primaryStage.setFullScreen(!primaryStage.isFullScreen());
           }
       });


       primaryStage.show();
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(100,200,100);" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller {
}
```

And you can watch this video to see what my issue is: https://youtu.be/7CFq7JXEPeE

(Main Screen = My Application, Screen in the top right = my 2nd monitor)
Basically, when I was trying to open spotify or firefox over my application, it wouldn't let me, the function putting it to the front doesn't fire either as you can see in the console, but the application still always stays on top and covers other applications.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra, updated it, sorry for causing any trouble, im new here